# Remove table row if the value of inout field is 0 using jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a dynamic table that I want to filter by removing the row that has a number field with a value of '0'. how can I achieve it using jquery?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none" id="orders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="">Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Delivery Date</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row0">
            <td>DSG</td>
            <td>GOLD DRAGON</td>
            <td>
                <input id="stock_in_qty_30" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="2113" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="2113">
            </td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>DSD</td>
            <td>SILVER DRAGON</td>
            <td><input id="stock_in_qty_31" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="0" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="0"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>PNKA05</td>
            <td>505</td>
            <td>
                <input id="stock_in_qty_32" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="0" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="0">
            </td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to add a button to be click by user to remove the row but I decided to discontinue it because I feel user will just be upset doing it. I am thinking if is possible for jquery to remove them (field with avalue of 0) upon page load? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can with `each` to iterate trought the different `input` in your dynamic table.

Then, you check each value and if the quantity is equal to 0, you can hide the row with the *hide* method.

```js
$('.quantity').each(function(){
  var qty = $(this).val();
  if (qty == 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').hide(); // or remove() to remove it from the DOM
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped m-b-none" id="orders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="">Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Delivery Date</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row0">
            <td>DSG</td>
            <td>GOLD DRAGON</td>
            <td>
                <input id="stock_in_qty_30" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="2113" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="2113">
            </td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td>DSD</td>
            <td>SILVER DRAGON</td>
            <td><input id="stock_in_qty_31" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="0" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="0"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td>PNKA05</td>
            <td>505</td>
            <td>
                <input id="stock_in_qty_32" class="form-control quantity" min="0" data-max="0" onkeyup="check(this);" name="stock_in_qty[]" type="number" value="0">
            </td>
            <td> <input class="form-control date" style="width:200px;" required="" name="delivery_date[]" type="date" value="2019-03-16"></td>
            <td> <input class="form-control" name="delivery_note[]" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```